# gpasm throws "Processor-header file mismatch" and "Processor type is undefined" errors

Tags: assembly, microchip, gpasm

Following [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/572887/124243), I'm trying to assemble the sample code from [this tutorial](https://www.circuitbread.com/tutorials/the-first-assembly-program-part-5-simple-microcontroller-pic10f200)

```
#include "p10f200.inc"
; CONFIG
    __CONFIG _WDT_OFF & _CP_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF
    ORG 0x0000
INIT ; We are initializing the microcontroller over the next three lines.
    MOVLW ~(1 << GP1)  ;these two lines set GP1 as an output
    TRIS GPIO
    BSF GPIO, GP1 ;this line is where we set GP1 output high to light the LED
LOOP 
    GOTO LOOP                          ; loop forever
END ; Needed to end the program.
```

I installed `gputils` following [this tutorial](http://www.thomasjenkins.net/tinkering/guides/10F200.html):

```
brew install gputils
```

and I have `gpasm-1.5.0 #1285 (Nov 15 2020)` installed properly. But when I run `gpasm -c test001.asm` I get the below errors:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gputils/1.5.0-1/share/gputils/header/p10f200.inc:34:Message[301] MESSAGE: "Processor-header file mismatch.  Verify selected processor."
/usr/local/Cellar/gputils/1.5.0-1/share/gputils/header/p10f200.inc:113:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "__MAXRAM"
/usr/local/Cellar/gputils/1.5.0-1/share/gputils/header/p10f200.inc:114:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "__BADRAM"
/usr/local/Cellar/gputils/1.5.0-1/share/gputils/header/p10f200.inc:115:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "__BADRAM"
test001.asm:6:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "__CONFIG"
test001.asm:7:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "ORG"
test001.asm:8:Error[150]   Labels must be defined in a code or data section when making an object file.
test001.asm:9:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "MOVLW"
test001.asm:10:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "TRIS"
test001.asm:11:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "BSF"
test001.asm:12:Error[150]   Labels must be defined in a code or data section when making an object file.
test001.asm:13:Error[131]   Processor type is undefined. "GOTO"
test001.asm:14:Warning[205] Found directive in column 1: "END"
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. I should have specified the processor I want to assemble for. One can do that either in the commands line:

```
gpasm -c -p p10f200 test001.asm
```

or by adding the line

```
list p=p10f200
```

at the beginning of the code.
plus the other warning:

> test001.asm:14:Warning[205] Found directive in column 1: "END"

can be resolved by adding a tab before the "END" line at the end of the code.

I used [this forum post](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m707570.aspx) as a reference. Also gpasm's documentations is [here](https://gputils.sourceforge.io/gputils.pdf).